# Perl: simultaneous socket connection

Tags: perl, sockets

Can I connect to array of hosts simultaneously?
When I try Socket

```
use Socket;
socket($s, AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, getprotobyname('tcp'));
my $addr = sockaddr_in(80, inet_aton("192.168.1.1"));
connect($s, $addr);
```

or IO::Socket

```
use IO::Socket;
my $s = IO::Socket::INET->new(PeerAddr => $ip , PeerPort => 80 , Proto => 'tcp' , Timeout => 5);
```

Is there any other way except forking and threading to avoid waiting on establishing connection?
The final expected result is array of opened socket handles.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to go low-level, you can use the built-in `select()` function to work out which sockets are readable/writable.  There's also the [IO::Socket](https://metacpan.org/pod/IO::Socket) that adds a more convenient API.

But a better answer is to use one of the event modules like [AnyEvent](https://metacpan.org/pod/AnyEvent).

Comment: I used IO::Select to avoid delay when reading from pipes or exchanging with remote server through already opened sockets.
But I don't understand how to avoid socket connection delay with Select ?

Comment: Hmm, not exactly sure about that. Did you set the `O_NONBLOCK` option before connecting?

Comment: Thanks!
I tried this before
IO::Socket::INET->new(PeerAddr => $ip , PeerPort => 80 , Proto => 'tcp' , Blocking => 0);
And it does not work. Now I set O_NONBLOCK on socket handle with fcntl() and connect() goes without delays! Looks like that it is what I need!